# Use of uninitialized value of size 8 leading to invalid read size?

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind

I am attempting to read a 2d matrix from a file I had generated previously.

I printed the matrix with this format:

```
rowNum
colNum --> in this case the value is 2
[row1,col1]
[row1,col2]
[row2,col1]
[row2,col2]
[row3,col1]
[row3,col2]
```

I then needed to write a function to read this array back and thus I wrote this:

```c
// Reads array. Takes file and address of arrayLength
int** readArray(char* file, int* arrayLengthNum) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");

    int bufferLength = 150;
    char buffer[bufferLength];
    
    fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp);
    int rows = atoi(buffer);
    fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp);
    int cols = atoi(buffer);

    int** arr = malloc(rows*sizeof(int));
    for(ssize_t i=0; i<rows ;i++) {
        arr[i]=malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
    }

    for(ssize_t j=0; j<(rows*cols); j++) {
        fgets(buffer, bufferLength, fp);
        printf("The buffer: %s", buffer);
        arr[j/cols][j%2]=(int)atoi(buffer);
    }
    // Need updating to val passed by ref
    *arrayLengthNum=rows;
    fclose(fp);
    return arr;
}
```

However, the code always returns SIGSEV. The valgrind output is as follows:

```
==2378== Invalid write of size 8
==2378==    at 0x110445: readArray (arraySaving.h:38)
==2378==    by 0x116A7D: main (main.c:108)
==2378==  Address 0x4ba0028 is 117,064 bytes inside a block of size 117,068 alloc'd
==2378==    at 0x483E77F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==2378==    by 0x110411: readArray (arraySaving.h:36)
==2378==    by 0x116A7D: main (main.c:108)
==2378== 
==2378== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==2378==    at 0x1104BF: readArray (arraySaving.h:43)
==2378==    by 0x116A7D: main (main.c:108)
==2378== 
==2378== Invalid read of size 8
==2378==    at 0x110495: readArray (arraySaving.h:43)
==2378==    by 0x116A7D: main (main.c:108)
==2378==  Address 0x4ba0030 is 4 bytes after a block of size 117,068 alloc'd
==2378==    at 0x483E77F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==2378==    by 0x110411: readArray (arraySaving.h:36)
==2378==    by 0x116A7D: main (main.c:108)
==2378== 
==2378== Invalid write of size 4
==2378==    at 0x1104BF: readArray (arraySaving.h:43)
==2378==    by 0x116A7D: main (main.c:108)
==2378==  Address 0x2f9800002eae is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2378== 
==2378== 
==2378== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==2378==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x2F9800002EAE
==2378==    at 0x1104BF: readArray (arraySaving.h:43)
==2378==    by 0x116A7D: main (main.c:108)
==2378==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==2378==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==2378==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==2378==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==2378==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==2378== 
==2378== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2378==     in use at exit: 351,676 bytes in 29,269 blocks
==2378==   total heap usage: 29,271 allocs, 2 frees, 356,796 bytes allocated
==2378== 
==2378== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2378==    definitely lost: 117,072 bytes in 14,634 blocks
==2378==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2378==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2378==    still reachable: 234,604 bytes in 14,635 blocks
==2378==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2378== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2378== 
==2378== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==2378== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==2378== ERROR SUMMARY: 13190 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

GDB however shows that it seems to be within bounds:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555c4bf in readArray (file=0x55555556357d "/home/user/matrix", 
    arrayLengthNum=0x7fffffffde10)
    at /home/user/filepath/arraySaving.h:43
43          arr[j/cols][j%2]=(int)atoi(buffer);
(gdb) print (int)atoi(buffer)
$1 = 119613727
(gdb) print j/cols
$2 = 14636
(gdb) print j
$3 = 29272
(gdb) print j%2
$4 = 0
(gdb)
```

Please let me know if there is any more information to include and thank you for your time!

Comment: `rows*sizeof(int) `-> `rows*sizeof(int*)`. You should check error. `fopen` can fail. `fgets` can fail. `atoi` can fail. `malloc` can fail.

Comment: yep! Thank you so much. Can't believe I overlooked that

Comment: @KamilCuk *`atoi` can fail*  But how can you tell?  ;-)  For all you other readers - **you can't**.  `atoi()` is a horrible function because it has no way to indicate any error - every single value it can return is a potentially correct result.  Nover use `atoi()` - use something like `strtol()` instead.